# crawling the stack overflow and getting url of any specified question

Tags: url, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
name = []
code = []
i=1
search1 = str(input('enter the word to search'))
search1= "+".join(search1.split())
address = "https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + search1
print(address)
res = requests.get(address)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all('a', class_='question-hyperlink')
for link in links:
    requests.get(address)
    print('link:' +link['href'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
```

This is my code. I want to extractURLl of my specified asked topic question ofStackOverfloww but the output I am getting is very random.

I want to extract the URL of any specified question, based on the given class.

Comment: Why are you not using their api? https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: I am new in python and web crawling both. I don't have any expertise to use the stackexchangeaAPI. Is there any way to get without using API